# Caesar cipher in JavaScript returning unexpected results

Tags: javascript, html, function, encode

I am creating a webpage to calculate a simple Caesar cipher without using jquery.  I cannot locate the error and I am not sure of how to return the new string to the text area.

HTML:

```
 <input type="button" value="Encrypt value = 1" onclick ="caesarEncipher(shift, text)"/>
```

javascript:

```
function caesarEncipher(shift, plaintext) {
  this.shift = shift;
  this.plaintext = plaintext;
  var ciphertext

  for (var i = 0; i < plaintext.length; i++) {
    // ASCII value - get numerical representation
    // 65 = 'A' 90 = 'Z'
    var encode = plaintext.charCodeAt(i);
    if (encode >= 65 && encode <= 90)
      // Uppercase
      ciphertext += String.fromCharCode((encode - 65 + shift) % 26 + 65);
      // 97 = 'a' 122 = 'z'
    else if (encode >= 97 && encode <= 122)
      // Lowercase
      ciphertext += String.fromCharCode((encode - 97 + shift) % 26 + 97);
    else
      ciphertext += input.charAt(i);
  }
  return document.getElementById = ciphertext; <-- Not sure about this
}
```

Comment: Why do you need `this.` here?

Comment: I don't need this, but am still used to my last java programming class.

Comment: Two things: Can you be more explicit about what is happing, and what the actual problem is (things like expected versus unexpected behaviour, actual error messages etc). Second, I've done it for your this time, please format your code properly when posting. Keep in mind if you want others to help, making your code look nice and clean (proper indentation, etc) significantly improves that experience.

Comment: Nothing is happening and everything I have tried is reporting no error, hence I can't find my mistake.  If I have a shift of 3 with the plaintext Hello", the output should be "Ebiil" in the textarea.  The first loop would iterate the length of plaintext using the ASCII or numerical value of the letter.  The first if is for uppercase, second for lowercase, and then for all other characters.  ciphertext would be the new string and pass it back to the textarea.  Nothing is being returned.

Comment: set `shift = -3` and you'll get your 'Ebiil' positive shift moves along the alphabet, negative - in reverse direction. `return document.getElementById = ciphertext;` this is wrong and no need in return

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/y9rv6bux/

```js
function encrypt(id, shiftId)
{
   var t = document.getElementById(id), out = '';
   var shift = parseInt(document.getElementById(shiftId).value);
   var txt = t.value, ranges = [[65,90],[97,122]];
    
   for(var i = 0; i < txt.length; i++)
   {
       var code = txt.charCodeAt(i);   
       for(var j = 0; j < ranges.length; j++)
       {
           if (code >= ranges[j][0] && code <= ranges[j][1])
           {
                code = ((code - ranges[j][0] + shift) %
                   (ranges[j][1] - ranges[j][0] + 1)) + ranges[j][0];
                break;
           }
       }
       out += String.fromCharCode(code);
   }
   t.value = out;
}
```

```html
<textarea id='t'></textarea><br><input type='text' id='s' value='1'><br>
<input type='button' onclick='encrypt("t", "s")' value='Go'>
```

Comment: Code with an explanation is rarely helpful.

Comment: @FelixKling it is the same code as TS', just written in slightly different manner. He'll see the difference in problematic areas.